# Upgrading Laptop

Tags: laptop

I have a old Compaq Presario v2000 laptop with Intel Centrino 1.5ghz processor and 768mb ram. i am planning to totally upgrade the laptop. Please let me know if i can change the mother board so that i can put in latest core i5 processor and increase ram to 2 gb. is it possible to upgrade the graphics as well. please let me know if these upgrades are possible, and which are the best parts for it

Comment: You should get a new laptop. In effect, all you are planning to keep are the peripherals (screen, keyboard, touchpad), and laptop motherboards are usually manufacturer/model specific. The USB ports, etc, are usually part of the motherboard too. Also, please read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), no shopping questions.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike desktops, laptops tend to be designed rather tightly, and generally you can't just fit any motherboard into any laptop.

I can't fit a motherboard from a previous series into my laptop, any more than i can fit in one from 5 years ago. Ram? Different. Even the internal display logic is changing - from LVDS to Idp.

Upgrade your laptop by buying a new one. Put the old one out to pasture, or as a spare laptop.

Laptops also tend to be a pain to take apart. The questions you're asking seem to hint that you think they are as modular and simple to work with as desktops. They arn't. They arn't standardised, are held together by a dozen little screws, and are a pain to work with.

Ram and hard drive upgrades are about the only things i think are worth doing, unless its a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the motherboard, the RAM, the hard drive, the CPU, but only to a certain point. If your laptop was top of the range at the time you bought it then it's unlikely you can get anything faster for it. As Bob said, you're better off getting a new laptop.

From experience, I upgraded my ThinkPad R50e not so long ago. I placed a 1.8Ghz Centrino processor in to it, along with 2GB RAM. That's as far as I could upgrade it to, and it hasn't made a noticeable difference to the performance of it. So, save the heartache and your money and invest in a brand new laptop.